# Best Model for judging if two images are similar

Tags: machine-learning

My dataset is in the form of pairs of images with a rating of 1 or 0. 1 indicates similar and 0 is dissimilar. The model has to be trained in such a way that it gives similarity between two input images not present in training. The number of classes is also indeterminate.

I have used ITML (Information Theoretic Metric Learning), LSML(Least Squares Metric Learning), and CSML (Cosine Similarity Metric Learning). So I have interpreted this problem as a metric learning problem.

Is there any other way to look at this problem or any other metric learning models I can use?

Comment: Look into this. https://github.com/jenssegers/imagehash

Comment: Thanks. This seems interesting. I will look into it.

Comment: You may want to ask machine learning related questions on the Stats Stack Exchange: https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I will do that too

Answer (score 0):

I think by your description that the key to your problem is **feature extraction** from the images, from which you can calculate a suitable metric for the problem at hand. When you have descriptive-enough features, most of the similarity measures you state could be useful.

By the way, your classes are not indeterminate. They are **0 (not-similar)** and **1 (similar)**, as you are formulating it as a classification problem.

Comment: Actually the problem is given a standard image, how close is the test image and then define 1 or 0. The number of standard images is not fixed. For example: Given an image of an apple, I have to judge if another image is of an apple. The algorithm should be robust enough if the object in consideration is changed to orange retraining is not required and it can give reasonable results.